Firebase email/ password authentication
I am using fire base email/password authentication in my android app in java. When I sign up with any email_id even if it does not exist, it does sign-up successful, only restriction is this that this id should contain @gmail.com at end. Kindly guide me why this happening and how to restrict to allow sign-up for only that id's that at actually email_id's. And also for valid email it say "sign-up failed"
Thanks
I have tried to make use of exception handling but could not get anything out of it. I am expacting something so that email authentication works well using firebase.

You can't prevent invalid emails with signups, but you can validate addresses by email.
